# How to loop all variables in VelocityContext?

Tags: java, velocity

In my Velocity template (.vm file) how can I loop through all the variables or attributes present in `VelocityContext`? In reference to the below code, I would like the template to write the names and count of all the fruits passed in context.

```
Map<String, Object> attribues = ...;
attribues.put("apple", "5");
attribues.put("banana", "2");
attribues.put("orange", "3");

VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext(attribues);
velocityEngine.mergeTemplate(templateLocation, encoding, velocityContext, writer);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default you can't do that, since you can't get hold of the context object. But you can put the context itself in the context.

Java:

```
attributes.put("vcontext", attributes);
```

.vm:

```
#foreach ($entry in $vcontext.entrySet())
  $entry.key => $entry.value
#end
```

Since you're reading the live context while also executing code that modifies the map, you're going to get exceptions. So it's best to make a copy of the map first:

```
#set ($vcontextCopy = {})
$!vcontextCopy.putAll($vcontext)
#foreach ($entry in $vcontextCopy.entrySet())
  ## Prevent infinite recursion, don't print the whole context again
  #if ($entry.key != 'vcontext' && $entry.key != 'vcontextCopy')
    $entry.key => $entry.value
  #end
#end
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a confirmation that this is not directly possible. However, when I execute your code Velocity's `Foreach.render` method is throwing a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Did this work for you? I am using Velocity 1.7.

Comment: Are you doing anything else besides printing the outcome, as in my example? One possibility would be that the `$entry` variable is added to the context after getting the entries, which would indeed trigger a `ConcurrentModificationException`. One quick workaround is to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of a simple `HashMap` for the `attributes` variable.

Comment: No, I am not doing anything besides the simple loop and printing. Using `ConcurrentHashMap` interestingly throws `StackOverflowError`! I am still going to accept your answer for confirming that there is no direct way to access the context from the template.

Comment: Strange, but `StackOverflowError` despite creating a copy!

Comment: Ah, I know, since the context contains itself, it will recursively keep trying to print itself indefinitely. The good news is that this means the script is working! To prevent this recursion, you need to manually exclude it. See the updated response.

Comment: Bravo! You nailed it finally. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> how can I loop through all the variables or attributes present in
>   `VelocityContext` ?

If I didn't misunderstood you, do you want to know how to loop through the key/value pairs contained in the map that you constructed your object with ?

If yes, you could call the method [`internalGetKeys()`](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.4/api/org/apache/velocity/VelocityContext.html#internalGetKeys%28%29) which will return the array of keys contained in the `VelocityContext` object. 
Then loop through all the keys and use [`internalGet()`](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.4/api/org/apache/velocity/VelocityContext.html#internalGet%28java.lang.String%29) to get the value associated with each key.

It would be something like this :

```
        VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext(attribues);
        Object[] keys = velocityContext.internalGetKeys();

        for(Object o : keys){
            String key = (String)o;
            String value = (String)velocityContext.internalGet(key);
            System.out.println(key+" "+value);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks ZouZou, I think you have correctly understood my problem. Could you please help me with how to call `internalGetKeys()` and `internalGet()` from the .vm template file? I am looking for the missing link in `#foreach($key in internalGetKeys()) $key #end`

Comment: Thanks again. However, I was looking for a way to call these methods from the Velocity template (.vm file).