# ConcurrentModificationException in Apache Velocity 1.7 with Java 8 and Ant 1.9

Tags: java, ant, concurrentmodification, apache-velocity

We have upgraded our project from java 7 and ant 1.8 to java 8 and ant 1.9.
In java 7, we were able to use apache velocity 1.7 without any issues. However after upgrading to java 8, we get ConcurrentModificationException.

```
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Foreach.render(Foreach.java:393)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTDirective.render(ASTDirective.java:207)
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:342)
at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:356)
at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:260)
at org.apache.velocity.texen.Generator.parse(Generator.java:445)
```

What could be the reason and the solution?

Comment: Possibly related post?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982791/how-to-loop-all-variables-in-velocitycontext